# For what $k\in\mathbb{N}$ does the equation $\phi(n)=k$ has no solution?

Tags: totient-function

Given that the Euler's phi-function, $\phi(n)$ is always even for $n>1$,

I understand that $\phi(n)$ is never odd other than $1$.

I wish to know for what $k\in\mathbb{N}$ does the equation $\phi(n)=2k$ has no solution?

Comment: If $m$ is an odd number such that $2m+1$ is not prime, then there is no solution to $\phi(n)=2m,$ for just the simplest even example.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Can you kindly supply proof, a link will do too? Thanks for responding.